# Installing drivers for an ATI HD4670

Tags: installation, drivers, ati

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC and now I'm trying to install the necessary drivers for my video card. I tried downloading the drivers from the ATI Radeon official site but the installer gives me the following error:

```
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 294: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: debclean: not found
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 295: ./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: dpkg-buildpackage: not found
[Error] Generate Package - error generating package : Ubuntu/quantal
```

After I reboot the the side-bar, the top-bar and the menu bar for opened windows disappear. The only way I can get everything to revert back to normal is to uninstall the drivers.

Is there any way to get ATI drivers to work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the origin of your error, but: There is a problem with the AMD legacy driver (which you need to run your ATI HD4670) which is not compatible with actual X-Server Version 1.13.

There exists a workaround, which downgrades your X-Server. This has not worked to me, but you may try it.

Further information:

- https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx
- http://ubuntuxtreme.com/howto/how-to-fix-your-amd-graphics-in-ubuntu-12-10/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that your problems are answered here in this guide which details how to do ATI installation which askubuntu have as a community wiki

[Ask Ubuntu ATI Community Wiki](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

You have solutions here also which talk you through how to fix it.

[Sorting ATI in Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.computersnyou.com/2012/10/Install-ATI-Catalist-Graphics-Driver-in-ubuntu-1210-how-to.html)

Let us know how you get on